# Using Zurb Foundation with django-cms

Tags: django, zurb-foundation, django-cms

I am a newbie web developer, I've installed django-cms and now I'm trying to figure out how to use zurb foundation with it to create frontend that I like.
Can you help me with understanding main steps I need to take to do this?

P.S.
I understand that maybe it is a simple question, but I can't find any tutorials about it. If you will help me - I promise to write extensive article about it so that other people wouldn't have problems with that =)

Answer (score 1):

Step one: Place foundation in the static directory

Step two: import the CSS like you normally would, using the STATIC_URL https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Step three: profit

I am not familiar with django-cms, but if you can locate the base template file the cms is using, it should be as simple as importing foundation using link rel= in that base template, then all your other templates will extend that base and have access to foundation CSS classes.

Comment: Step two: import the generated CSS and any JavaScript components you want to use. 

Then look for your templates folder. There are like 4 templates you have to modify to take advantage of Foundation. But they are simple templates and not too bad to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it seems like @Wade Willams answer will only expose the Foundation CSS framework for use.  Foundation, however, offers a bit more functionality as a framework than simply a responsively constructed CSS file.

From [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324170/how-to-integrate-foundation-5-in-django) I found [django-zurb-foundation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation) which looks promising.

Comment: Foundation is only a frontend framework. It is comprised of CSS and JavaScript. You can incorporate the Foundation static files in your Django templates and make full use of Zurb Foundation.