# How to integrate Foundation 5 in django

Tags: django, zurb-foundation

I'd like to starting use Foundation 5 in a django project.
My doubts are about how to setup folders of Foundation project.
Foundation now uses bower for js dipendencies.
I think it's not correct make a foundation 5 set up into the static folder of django.

Has anyone done a setup of foundation in a django project?

To compile scss files I'll use django-compressor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My solution is use [django-bower](https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower)... that's all!

Comment: Personally I recommend https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation as mentioned in different answer...

Answer (score 7):

Check here. It should have all the instructions.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation

Answer (score 3):

I've been playing with foundation on my django project using the django development server. All I did was download the Foundation 5 static files (JS,CSS) and add them to my django static files. Then I added in the necessary scripts to my base template as shown here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/css.html. I haven't put it into production yet but I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work or why using static files isn't correct (as you thought in your question).

There are benefits to compiling the CSS yourself with SASS if you're really hardcore and I imagine that using template tags with django-zurb-foundation is a little cleaner or maybe easier to implement if you have tons of templates that you would need to modify but if you're like me and you just want to try Foundation out on a small project then downloading the extra applications (django-bower, django-zurb-foundation) isn't necessary.