# What is the benefit of using a Foundation Django Package compared to just putting the Foundation files in Static

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates, zurb-foundation

I am currently learning Django and I am confused on how to use Foundation in my project. I read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324170/how-to-integrate-foundation-5-in-django) and it seems that I can either just put the files in my static folder or install a package such as [Django-zurb-foundation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-zurb-foundation/5.1.1). Is there any benefit of using one method over the other? Or is it just a matter of preference? I don't plan on using SCSS but would occasionally edit the foundation css file to change primary colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you gain by using the django-zurb-foundation package, perhaps its saves you by providing some boilerplate code, but from the looks of it, it still requires you to apply the Foundation sauce to forms and stuff. So i would recommend sticking to the static method, the package will just clutter the codebase.